# how to find words with 4 letters, where second letter is a, in c language

Tags: c, string, substring

I just want to ask if anyone could show me a sample program on how to find and printf all words that contains four letters , and second letter is 'a' ?
input String is given by user.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: You should define what is a word for you, and what alphabet -and character encoding- are you using. Does `€abç` fits your criteria?

Answer (score 1):

What you need :

write a c program main function

read a line input ex scanf into char string[1024]

check its length

strlen(string) == 4

check second letter is a lowercase 'a'

string[1] == 'a'

after rereading i think input string is a list of word (separated by ??) so a string parser could be needed.

Then compile it with you c compiler ( which is ? gcc ? )

Show us your code.

Comment: actually I think the program will be significantly more complicated then this (or else I misunderstand what the OP wants).  I suspect something more along these lines:
a. get a string from user
b. if len < 4 exit
c. if no 'a' in string exit
d. build all possible 4 letter permutations from the string
e. discard all that do not have 'a' as second character
f. discard any that are not a word (in dictionary?)

But I agree, show us work first, and then ask specific questions.

Comment: Occam's razor => among competing hypotheses, the one with the fewest assumptions should be selected.